# How to build a amount screen for flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is anyone knows how to build a screen in flutter like the image below?

[image: Valid XHTML].

The initial digit will start from "0.00" and it keep adding the digit when you keep pressing on the number pad.

Updated. This is the code I have changed based on the code that Yamin provided.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AddDigits(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddDigits extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddDigitsState createState() => _AddDigitsState();
}

class _AddDigitsState extends State<AddDigits> {
  String _total = '0.00';
  String _tmp = '';

  addDigit(int value) {
    if (_tmp.indexOf('0') == 0) _tmp = _tmp.substring(1, _tmp.length);
    setState(() {
      _tmp += value.toString();
      if (_tmp.length == 1) _total = '0.0' + _tmp.toString();

      if (_tmp.length == 2) _total = '0.' + _tmp.toString();

      if (_tmp.length > 2) {
        _total = _tmp.substring(0, _tmp.length - 2) +
        '.' +
            _tmp.substring(_tmp.length - 2);
      }
    });
  }

  removeDigit() {
    var _tmpValue = _total;
    if (_tmpValue.length > 3) {
      var _fortmp = _tmpValue.substring(0, _tmpValue.length - 3) +
      _tmpValue.substring(_tmpValue.length - 2);
      _fortmp = _fortmp.substring(0, _fortmp.length - 1);
      _tmpValue = _fortmp.substring(0, _fortmp.length - 2) +
      '.' +
      _fortmp.substring(_fortmp.length - 2);
      setState(() {
        _total = _tmpValue;
        _tmp = _fortmp;
      });
    }

    if (_tmpValue.length == 3) {
      _tmpValue = _tmpValue.substring(_tmpValue.length - 2);
      setState(() {
        _total = '0.' + _tmpValue;
        if (_tmp == '00')
          _tmp = '';
        else
          _tmp = _tmpValue;
      });
   }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(image: backgroundImage),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[Text("Total: " + _total.toString())],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              NumKey(
                value: 1,
                callBack: addDigit,
              ),
              NumKey(value: 2, callBack: addDigit),
              NumKey(value: 3, callBack: addDigit),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              NumKey(value: 4, callBack: addDigit),
              NumKey(value: 5, callBack: addDigit),
              NumKey(value: 6, callBack: addDigit),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              NumKey(value: 7, callBack: addDigit),
              NumKey(value: 8, callBack: addDigit),
              NumKey(value: 9, callBack: addDigit),
            ],
           ),
           Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
               Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: MaterialButton(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/delete.png',
                      width: 25.0, height: 25.0),
                  onPressed: () => {removeDigit()},
                ),
               ),
              NumKey(value: 0, callBack: addDigit),
               Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: MaterialButton(
                   child: Image.asset('assets/success.png',
                      width: 25.0, height: 25.0),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
           )
        ],
       ),
    );
  }
}

class NumKey extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  Function callBack;

  NumKey({@required this.value, @required this.callBack});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: MaterialButton(
        // backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
         child: Text(value.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
         onPressed: () => {callBack(value)},
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

The code above is working but I just wanted to know is there any better implementation since I am dealing with many substring in order to make it work.

I really need help on this. thanks

Comment: Add the code you have tried and what problem you are facing with it.

Comment: Sorry. I have really no any idea on this. I have a number pad with my implementation now but i really have no idea on the amount field.

Comment: take a textfield for amount field and initially set it to 0.00 and as any number pressed update it accordingly

Comment: @primo like how to set accordingly? i did try with with string += value. but i cant make the decimal.

Comment: take a reference of a calculator app and build you logic for this accordingly

Comment: yes i am trying with the calculator app that provided by Yamin. I am currently thinking if mask can make it accordingly. but no luck

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to develop such a thing. I prepared an idea and you can find it below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AddDigits(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddDigits extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddDigitsState createState() => _AddDigitsState();
}

class _AddDigitsState extends State<AddDigits> {
  int _total = 0;

  addDigit(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _total += value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[Text("Total: " + _total.toString())],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            NumKey(
              value: 1,
              callBack: addDigit,
            ),
            NumKey(value: 2, callBack: addDigit),
            NumKey(value: 3, callBack: addDigit),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            NumKey(value: 4, callBack: addDigit),
            NumKey(value: 5, callBack: addDigit),
            NumKey(value: 6, callBack: addDigit),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            NumKey(value: 7, callBack: addDigit),
            NumKey(value: 8, callBack: addDigit),
            NumKey(value: 9, callBack: addDigit),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                child: Text('<'),
                onPressed: () => {},
              ),
            ),
            NumKey(value: 0, callBack: addDigit),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                child: Text('ok'),
                onPressed: () => {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NumKey extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  Function callBack;

  NumKey({@required this.value, @required this.callBack});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        child: Text(value.toString()),
        onPressed: () => {callBack(value)},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi yamin, thanks for the help. but i still dont know how to concat the string like decimal. The app that I showed in the picture will go from '0.00' to '0.01' to '0.11' to '1.11' if u keep pressing. Do you know what is the name of this so i can find it out through online?

Comment: Dear. You are asking for a complete source code here. Stack overflow is for asking questions not asking for an app. If you read the whole docs of dart and flutter I'm pretty sure that you will find out how to write it. You are welcome to contact me directly if you needed any help.

Comment: I am not asking for source code here but I really got no idea on what should I use to achieve this. How can i contact you directly?

Comment: send me a mail. we will talk on skype or whatsapp: yamin.tashakkori@gmail.com

Comment: Please see my updated code. it is working now. but any advice by doing it with a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"? there isn't a "best way" for every scenario. you should learn the most common ways, find their pros and cons and then choose the most suitable solution for your current purpose.